# Error building DependencyGraph: Error: Naming collision detected

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm running very simple code using react-native-tableview

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var { AppRegistry } = React;
var TableView = require('react-native-tableview');
var Section = TableView.Section;
var Item = TableView.Item;

class AwesomeProject extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <TableView style={{flex:1}}
                       allowsToggle={true}
                       allowsMultipleSelection={true}
                       tableViewStyle={TableView.Consts.Style.Grouped}
                       tableViewCellStyle={TableView.Consts.CellStyle.Subtitle}
                       onPress={(event) => console.log(event)}>
                <Section label="Section 1" arrow={true}>
                    <Item value="1" detail="Detail1" >Item 1</Item>
                    <Item value="2">Item 2</Item>
                </Section>
                <Section label="Section 2" arrow={false}>
                    <Item selected={true}>Item 1</Item>
                    <Item>Item 2</Item>
                    <Item>Item 3</Item>
                </Section>
            </TableView>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react-native": "^0.17.0",
  "react-native-navbar": "^1.1.6",
  "react-native-router": "^0.2.1",
  "react-native-tableview": "^1.4.6"
}
```

And I get the error:

```
Error building DependencyGraph:
 Error: Naming collision detected: /Users/sandbox/native/test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-router/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js collides with /Users/sandbox/native/test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (HasteMap.js:123:13)
    at HasteMap.js:94:28
    at tryCallOne (/Users/sandbox/native/test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/sandbox/native/test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/Users/sandbox/native/test/AwesomeProject/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

I noticed that much people come across with this problem, but still there is no clear solution which library is guilty and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates there are two copies of `String.prototype.es6.js` and the packager isn't able to ignore one of them and thus you are receiving the error.

Are you using npm2 or npm3? As a workaround, npm3 will flatten the dependencies which should allow you to move forward by de-duping react (assuming you ensure they are both pointed at the same version).

You can either [install npm3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm3#installation--update) as a separate global package and then run `npm3 install` or you can upgrade your entire npm package via `npm install -g npm@3.0-latest`. Also, make sure you remove the contents of your `node_modules` directory before re-installing your npm packages should you choose to upgrade.

There are pros and cons with this approach and react-native might include React as a peer dependency down the road which may mitigate this issue. It doesn't seem like `react-native-router` necessarily needs regular `React` since the components being used are dependent on `react-native` so it may be worth forking this repo and removing the direct dependencies on React if you're still having trouble with `npm3` or don't wish to use it.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've got it on GitHub as well, and yes `react-native-router` used an old version of react-native, now it's fixed https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router/commit/8ee6c940b025bfe69e1033bf15af14f55faae4e6 but not published yet